# Can the fugitive escape?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, strategy, game, game-theory

A fugitive is surrounded by N police officers, with the nearest one at distance 1 away. The fugitive and the officers move alternatively.

- In a fugitive move, the fugitive can travel no more than a distance of d.
- In an officer move, the sum of distances travelled by all officers can be no more than d.

The fugitive is caught if their distance to some officer is 0 in finite moves, otherwise they escape.

Question: Given N, is there always some $d \gt 0$ for which the fugitive can escape, regardless of the officers' initial distribution?

---

Related: [One king vs many. Can white force a draw?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109445/one-king-vs-many-can-white-force-a-draw) (discrete version dual problem)

Comment: Can the officers occupy the same area as each other (distance of 0)? Can all the officers start a distance of 1 away, or only one?

Comment: @bobble  They can occupy the same spot. All of them can start at distance 1 away.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing the quantifiers on your question here - is it "Given some fixed N, is there a single d that works for every distribution of N officers", or "can you find a d for any particular distribution of officers"? (Also, I assume that d is required to be positive?)

Comment: @Deusovi It's the former, and of course d is positive.

Comment: I assume all players are on a continuous plane and not on some sort of grid/lattice ?

Comment: @JimN Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer (a crude upper bound):

> for sufficiently large $N$ (at least, it works for magnitudes of about $20$), if such $d$ exists, it must be $$d<\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\sin\frac\pi N$$

Because

> Assume that the officers stand on the unit circle in the vertices of a regular $N$-gon inscribed into that circle. The distance between the officers than will be $2 \sin\frac\pi N$, the side length of such a polygon.
>  On the other side, if the distance between officers is $d\sqrt3$ or less (i.e. when $d$ is too large), then the common chord of the 2 circles with radii $d$ centered on the adjacent officers will have length of $d$ or greater, so the fugitive cannot pass inbetween these officers to cross the boundary. So, $2\sin\frac\pi N > d\sqrt3$, and we have the bound for $d$ written above.
>  OF course, the $d>1$ case won't work for sufficiently large value of $N$, since after making the first move, the fugitive will be at a distance of $d-1$ from the circle, and $d-1+\varepsilon$ from the closest officer, where $\varepsilon$ is much less then 1 for large $N$, so the fugitive will be caught next move.

Answer (score 0):

**No, the fugitive cannot escape with large N**

Assume an arbitrarily large number of officers surrounding the fugitive, all standing 1 unit away from the fugitive on the perimeter of the unit circle centered on the fugitive. The fugitive cannot end his move within distance *d* of any officer, or that officer can catch him next turn.

In the limit of an infinite number of officers, the "disallowed" region for the fugitive is an annulus with width *2d*. The fugitive cannot cross a width of *2d* in a single move if his maximum move length is *d*. If *d* > 1, the "disallowed" region is a circle of radius *d*+1, which also cannot be escaped with a single move of length *d*.

NOTE: This reasoning is incorrect, as you can always pick *d* smaller than half the distance between officers, so that the "disallowed" region is just a series of circles and not an annulus. There can always be a viable escape path in the initial configuration, so long as *d* is small enough.

Comment: The value of $d$ can depend on $N$. If $d$ is small enough (much less than the spacing between officers), this strategy may not work, as far a I can see. However, it does not mean that the officers can act in some other way (they can move too etc.)

Comment: @trolley813 Hmm, very good point. Regardless of N, you can always make the "disallowed" region *not* an annulus by picking small enough *d*, so that premise is incorrect. There can always be a "hole" to escape in the initial configuration.

Comment: But at least, this strategy provides an upper bound (I'm writing my own answer about it).